# Localization of a triangulated category

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

I am writing here because I need to understand better some topics about [homological algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homological_algebra).

I am reading the online notes [*Algèbre Homologique Quasi-Abélienne*](http://www.anmath.ulg.ac.be/fp/rec/dea.pdf) on homological algebra in a quasi-abelian setting.

Proposition $1.2.8$ has the proof of: localized of triangulated is triangulated.

They want to prove TD$4$ axiom for the localization using the corollary $1.1.8$.
The corollary $1.1.8$ needs the homological character of $\text{Hom}(-,-)$ (proposition $1.1.7$).
To prove the homologicity of $\text{Hom}(-,-)$ TD$4$ is needed.

Do you know another way to prove that the localization of triangulated category is triangulated?

(With all the passages)

Or is there something that I cannot reach?

Sorry if my English is not good.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A very good and standard reference is the book by Gelfand and Manin, Methods in homological algebra, section IV.2, Theorem 2

Comment: @Nikio, Thank you for answering me. I will check more accurately this reference. I found also here         
[link](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/derived.pdf#nameddest=05QI)         
 an interesting proof of the property I asked.